# matlab what is the difference between imresize and interp2

Tags: matlab

I have an image that I want to make the width and length both twice of the original size (means 4 times the original area). I was using `imresize(X,2)` but I was told I should use `interp2` instead.

I know `imresize` uses bicubic interpolation by default and there are other options. So what is the difference between `imresize` and `interp2`?

Comment: To add to Dan's answer, one more option for `interp2` is, it can utilize the `spline` option and do cubic spline interpolation. This option involves solving a linear system and is not provided in `imresize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`imresize` takes different inputs from `interp2`. With `interp2` you cannot specify a simple multiplication factor that you want to scale your image by the way you can with `imresize`. `interp2` does 2D interpolation and instead of a scale input you need to provide it with the x-y coordinates of the points between the pixels that you want to interpolate. `imresize` uses interpolation internally, but it it does a fair amount of other processing and calculations beforehand. `imresize` also allows you to shrink your image which is not quite as straightforward using just `interp2`. Internally they will use the same maths, `imresize` just makes the task of resizing an image easier for you.